# Gradle Could not find tools.jar

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, desktop, gradlew

I am trying to make a game with LibGdx. I love it! It is sooo simple and a lot better than JME3 and LWJGL. But trying to package it I am having an error. Here is an image of the gui for Gradle: http://prntscr.com/845kyx and here is a the full debug error: http://pastebin.com/ugdfySg1 Now I don't know how to debug those errors and what not, so I hope someone can help. I have also tried to re-create the entire project, and make it a eclipse valid project, instead of just Gradle. None of that worked.
[image]

Comment: Can you please include the screenshots and error log in your post?

Comment: I did they are at the links http://prntscr.com/845kyx and http://pastebin.com/ugdfySg1

Comment: I meant if you could include them directly, not as links. If these services are defunct, your question and the answers become useless for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to set the system property "java.home" and the environment variable JAVA_HOME to a valid JDK.

To set the environment variable run:
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64`

Comment: i think you can elaborate this answer, like how to set system property in linux etc

Comment: Also add the following command: `export PATH="${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin"`

Answer (score 36):

I have a file called `gradle.properties` at the root of my project with the following property:

```
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74
```

`org.gradle.java.home` needs to point to a valid JDK location.

Without this file, I get the same error (Could not find tools.jar). With the file present, this is no longer an issue.

Comment: Not usable across several developers with different configurations!

Comment: @MarkusL your statement is correct. Each developer must create his or her own gradle.properties. The file is not intended for sharing.

Comment: this worked for me when i set it to this in the gradle.properties
```org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/```

Answer (score 28):

For me was solution this:

```
yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```

Or for newer CentOS/Fedora/RHEL versions:

```
dnf install java-devel
```

Comment: For me that works in Fedora 24+: `sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Comment: Faced same issue while I was trying to install voldemort kv store on centos 7.2  yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel solved for me

Answer (score 14):

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Fixed it for me for a Jenkins job.

Comment: Alternately, `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: At least in Ubuntu Xenial package `openjdk-8-jdk-headless` provides `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/tools.jar`

Comment: On my WSL only `openjdk-8-jdk` has tools.jar ,`openjdk-8-jdk-headless` doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

If we already have a lot of different distro answers I might as well add the Arch answer:

```
sudo pacman -S jdk8-openjdk
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me as a temporary solution. At the root of my project in "gradle.properties" file I have line:

```
org.gradle.java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/
```